# Selecting rows that contain Non-ASCII characters

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Here is the issue: I have imported about 20000 game descriptions from mochimedia into my database, but there are many foreign games, which I do not want to list.

I came up with this query to find columns with non-ASCII characters

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NOT HEX(COLUMN) REGEXP '^([0-7][0-9A-F])*$';
```

Note that I found this solution here on stackoverflow as I am not an expert if it comes to mysql queries.

However, while this query catches quiet a few foreign descriptions, it also seems to fail sometimes and finds perfectly fine descriptions, so what I am looking for is finetuning this query to skip the "okay" ones.

Here are a few returned rows that are "okay", meaning they should not be returned:

> Game Boy Jam game that uses game boy restrictions. It’s a western
>   platform game, where you play as a sheriff of the town. Your mission
>   is to capture all the bad bandits in the land and bring them to
>   justice.

and one more

> It's hard to be a kitten if you have such a clumsy owner! Yesterday
>   she lost a lot of things in the park and now it's up to you to find
>   them!
>
> Memories of that day can be helpful – you should remember where have
>   you seen that thing last and search there.Map also can be usefull for
>   your task. And finally you can climb up a tree and ask a big cat for a
>   hint – you will see all the events of that day again.
>
> But sometimes it's not enough to just find a lost thing. Some
>   residents of the park may already be using it for themselves – be it
>   mice or ants. In that case you may have to bring them something in
>   exchange for a lost thing – only then you will get it back.

and one last example

> Hungry honey bee is a unique fun game. It includes the fun of a
>   platform game, puzzle game, adventure game, role playing game. In this
>   fantasy game, one needs to make honey bee to collect all the flowers
>   in order to win a match. As level progresses new challenges will be
>   introduced with gradually toughness. Overall it’s a complete blend of
>   fun which makes one stick with the game for hours. GOI: Rating 4.5 our
>   of 5

Please remember that I am not a mysql expert, so I can only guess what the issue is, and my guess is that some of the characters like the

’ in It’s or the characters – and :

might cause this.

Maybe someone would be willing to share a optimized query to solve this problem? I spent quiet a few time with this but given the fact that I am still a newbie with php and absolutely not an expert with REGEXP and mysql queries, it would be nice to get some help here so I can improve my knowledge. Please do not assume that I will understand anything you say if you just throw it at me, so detailed help would be wonderful.

Thanks for your time reading this.

Comment: They're not necessarily "foreign", and that in itself is a matter of perspective. For some, "ç" or "ß" is not foreign at all. What you mean is "Non-ASCII". Even "ö" is used in English on occasion.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I changed the title to keep this less confusing.

Comment: Yes, a veritable smörgåsbord of possibilities ;-)

Comment: This regex will accept only [ASCII](http://www.ascii-code.com/): `^(\x20-\xff])*$` - please note that things like `ö` and `ß` ARE valid ASCII values. If you want to ignore the extended ASCII values your regex will look like this: `^(\x20-\x7e)*$` but be aware that will omit things like dashes and quotation marks...

Comment: The problem is obviously in encoding. When you try to run this query - `select hex("It’s")` it returns `4974E2809973` %E2 %80 %99 being the UTF-8 bytes for ’. It´s copied from the first example of failed description.

Comment: @BennyHill [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is strictly 7-bit. Extended-ASCII, such as the ANSI standard version, are technically different even though it's often called "ASCII". The one you've linked to is actually [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Answer (score 8):

If you're simply trying to find columns which contain non-ASCII characters, you can use the query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column != CONVERT(column USING ASCII);
```